# Implement same Encryption and Decryption Technique in SQL Server as implemented in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, encryption

I created two methods Encrypt() and Decrypt() in my Web Application for Encrypting and Decrypting Data.

Now, I want to use same technique in my SQL Server Database for Decrypting Data.

Can anyone tell me how is it possible.

Please help!!

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: You might be able to use the CLR using a SQL Server Database Project and write functions in .NET to be called from SQL, would save you writing it all in SQL.

Comment: Hi Lloyd,
Thanks for replying, can you explain in detail how can I do this?.

Answer (score 1):

Even though is theoretically possible to load your functions as SQLCLR, you will get key management wrong. Use SQL Server [cryptographic functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) and discard everything you wrote yourself. Use a proper [key hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx).